# Syntax error after SET Password=$password

Tags: php, mysql

> **Error:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE Username=''' at line 1

Code below:

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET Password=$pass_word WHERE Username='$_POST[username]'";
```

Comment: Never use this code in production. It's vulnerable to SQL Injection. Look up how to use stored procedures before you use SQL queries in php.

Comment: Please read more about sql injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 0):

This is **very** risky coding. What if someone (traditionally referred to as [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)) changed his password to

```
 hello';--
```

and your query became

```
UPDATE users SET Password='hello';-- ' WHERE Username='$_POST[username]'";
```

which -- being a comment, gets interpreted as a very broad

```
UPDATE users SET Password='hello';
```

Your error *now* was that you forgot the quotes around the password -- but what you should do is move to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/it/book.pdo.php). Then your query might become

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE users SET Password=? WHERE Username=?');
$stmt->execute($pass_word, $_POST['username']);
```

with the PDO layer taking care of avoiding troubles.

The same thing applies to `$_POST[username]`, and I suggest you write it as "{$_POST['username']}" - it's more easily parsed by several PHP tools, and allows you more flexibility with complex arrays.

Comment: much appreciated, thanks